# How to Implement MaxEncodedLen Trait for Structs Containing Vec<u8> in Rust

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, rust

i'm trying to create a blockchain runtime module using `Substrate`. I have defined a few data structures with the `#[derive(MaxEncodedLen)]` attribute, but I'm running into a problem when trying to compile the code. Specifically, the compiler is giving an error for structures containing `Vec<u8>`.

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(AccountId, Data, Quantity))]
pub struct Collection<AccountId, Data, Quantity> {
    /// Class metadata
    pub metadata: Vec<u8>,
    //...
}

#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(AccountId))]
pub struct ShareProfitsInfo<AccountId> {
    /// Token metadata
    pub percentage: Vec<u8>,
    //...
}

#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(AccountId, Data))]
pub struct NFT<AccountId, Data> {
    /// Token metadata
    pub metadata: Vec<u8>,
    //...
}
```

The compiler error message is:

```
no function or associated item named max_encoded_lenfound for structVec<u8>in the current scope function or associated item not found inVec<u8>`
```

As I understand, the `MaxEncodedLen` trait isn't implemented for `Vec<u8>`, but I'm not sure how to go about solving this issue. How can I implement `MaxEncodedLen` for my structures containing `Vec<u8>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vec` can never be `MaxEncodedLen` (MEL), since it does not have a sensible maximal encode length.
You can use `BoundedVec<T, L>`. It directly implements `MaxEncodedLen` and has a limited maximal length.
Now inductively the `T` also needs to be MEL. The MEL of the `BoundedVec` can then be calculated at compile time.

For example `BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<32>>` is a vector that can have at most 32 bytes. Its MEL will be slightly larger than 32 bytes though, because it has to prefix its length like all vectors do.
You can take a look at the [convition-voting-pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e374a33fe1d99d59eb24a08981090bdb4503e81b/frame/conviction-voting/src/vote.rs#L177) for a complete example of how to do it.